Creating new items after importing a Wikibase XML dump
I'm creating a local copy of a Wikibase instance, using the exact steps as recommended here. The error I'm running across appears at first very similar to what is discussed in this StackOverflow question, although the solution does not work.
First, I create a Wikibase dump from a Wikibase.Cloud instance using the MediaWiki Dump Generator: dumpgenerator https://furry.wikibase.cloud/ --xml --exnamespaces 640 (this is a smaller dump so it doesn't take too longer to upload).
Next, I create the Wikibase Docker instance by following the steps here for the extended install. I launched this by running docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.extra.yml up -d .
Then I run:
#!/bin/sh

# Load config.ini
source config.ini

cd "$WBDOCKERPATH"

# Run docker-compose to set up Wikibase Suite instance.
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.extra.yml up -d

# Run update and install vim.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "apt -y update"
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "apt-get -y update"
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "apt-get -y install apt-file"
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "apt-file update"
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "apt-get -y install vim"

# Clone WikibaseLexeme, making sure to use the REL1_41 branch.
if [ ! -d "$WBWRAPPERPATH/WikibaseLexeme" ]; then
    git clone -b REL1_41 https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/extensions/WikibaseLexeme.git "$WBWRAPPERPATH/WikibaseLexeme"
fi
docker cp "$WBWRAPPERPATH/WikibaseLexeme" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/www/html/extensions/WikibaseLexeme

# Load WikibaseLexeme.
if winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "grep -Fxq \"wfLoadExtension( 'WikibaseLexeme' );\" /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php";
then
    :
else
    winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "echo \"wfLoadExtension( 'WikibaseLexeme' );\" >> /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php"
fi

# Run update script.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "php /var/www/html/maintenance/update.php --force"

# Copy XML dump into the Docker container.
docker cp "$XMLDUMPPATH" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/tmp/dump.xml

# Update LocalSettings.php to allow for entity import.
if winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "grep -Fxq \"\$wgWBRepoSettings['allowEntityImport'] = true;\" /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php";
then
    :
else
    winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "echo '$'\"wgWBRepoSettings['allowEntityImport'] = true;\" >> /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php"
fi

# Import dump.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c  "php /var/www/html/maintenance/importDump.php < /var/tmp/dump.xml"

# Perform rebuild.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "php /var/www/html/maintenance/rebuildall.php"

# Run jobs.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "php /var/www/html/maintenance/runJobs.php --memory-limit 512M"

# Initalize site statistics.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "php /var/www/html/maintenance/initSiteStats.php --update"

# Download counter rebuilding script.
if [ ! -f "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql" ]; then
    curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JeroenDeDauw/c86a5ab7e2771301eb506b246f1af7a6/raw/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql -o "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql"
fi

# Copy rebuilding script to the Docker container.
docker cp "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/www/html/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql

# Run rebuild script.
winpty docker exec -it wbdocker-wikibase-1 //bin//bash -c "php /var/www/html/maintenance/sql.php /var/www/html/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql"

After running this, whenever I attempt to add a new item, property, or lexeme, I get the error Could not create a new page. It already exists..
I've tried a few different solutions so far, but I run into the same error each time:

Removing Wikibase lexemes.
Adding a test item and deleting it before the import.
Using a bot to add and delete the test item.
Trying the add/delete test item script between every step (it seems to succeed up until the runJobs.php step is run, but that hasn't helped expose anything so far).
Create a complete log to search for errors (nothing found, everything seemed to run correctly; note that this output is the test run without WikibaseLexeme, but the log with WikibaseLexeme is basically the same):

$ bash wbdocker_wrapper.sh
time="2024-06-24T09:43:08-04:00" level=warning msg="C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\Documents\\Research Projects\\[DATABASE]\\wbdocker\\docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete"
time="2024-06-24T09:43:08-04:00" level=warning msg="C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\Documents\\Research Projects\\[DATABASE]\\wbdocker\\docker-compose.extra.yml: `version` is obsolete"
 Network wbdocker_default  Creating
 Network wbdocker_default  Created
 Volume "wbdocker_elasticsearch-data"  Creating
 Volume "wbdocker_elasticsearch-data"  Created
 Volume "wbdocker_mediawiki-mysql-data"  Creating
 Volume "wbdocker_mediawiki-mysql-data"  Created
 Volume "wbdocker_quickstatements-data"  Creating
 Volume "wbdocker_quickstatements-data"  Created
 Volume "wbdocker_shared"  Creating
 Volume "wbdocker_shared"  Created
 Volume "wbdocker_query-service-data"  Creating
 Volume "wbdocker_query-service-data"  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-mysql-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-elasticsearch-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-proxy-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-elasticsearch-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-mysql-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-jobrunner-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-proxy-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-frontend-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-jobrunner-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-frontend-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-quickstatements-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-updater-1  Creating
 Container wbdocker-quickstatements-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-updater-1  Created
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-elasticsearch-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-mysql-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-mysql-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-jobrunner-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-proxy-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-elasticsearch-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-proxy-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-quickstatements-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-frontend-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-updater-1  Starting
 Container wbdocker-wikibase-jobrunner-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-updater-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-wdqs-frontend-1  Started
 Container wbdocker-quickstatements-1  Started

...

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
STEP 3

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

MediaWiki 1.41.1 Updater

Your composer.lock file is up to date with current dependencies!
Going to run database updates for my_wiki
Depending on the size of your database this may take a while!
Abort with control-c in the next five seconds (skip this countdown with --quick)
 ...0
...collations up-to-date.
...have rev_actor field in revision table.
...watchlist_expiry table already exists.
...page_restrictions field does not exist in page table, skipping modify field p
atch.
...index ipb_address_unique already set on ipblocks table.
...archive table does not contain ar_text_id field.
...lc_lang is up-to-date.
...ll_lang is up-to-date.
...site_language is up-to-date.
...index ipb_address_unique on table ipblocks has no field ipb_anon_only; added.
...ipb_address_unique index up-to-date.
...actor_name in table actor already modified by patch patch-actor-actor_name-va
rbinary.sql.
...site_global_key in table sites already modified by patch patch-sites-site_glo
bal_key.sql.
...iwl_prefix in table iwlinks already modified by patch patch-extend-iwlinks-iw
l_prefix.sql.
...rd_title in table redirect already modified by patch patch-redirect-rd_title-
varbinary.sql.
...pl_title in table pagelinks already modified by patch patch-pagelinks-pl_titl
e-varbinary.sql.
...tl_title field does not exist in templatelinks table, skipping modify field p
atch.
...il_to in table imagelinks already modified by patch patch-imagelinks-il_to-va
rbinary.sql.
...ll_title in table langlinks already modified by patch patch-langlinks-ll_titl
e-varbinary.sql.
...iwl_title in table iwlinks already modified by patch patch-iwlinks-iwl_title-
varbinary.sql.
...cat_title in table category already modified by patch patch-category-cat_titl
e-varbinary.sql.
...qc_title in table querycache already modified by patch patch-querycache-qc_ti
tle-varbinary.sql.
...qcc_title in table querycachetwo already modified by patch patch-querycachetw
o-qcc_title-varbinary.sql.
...wl_title in table watchlist already modified by patch patch-watchlist-wl_titl
e-varbinary.sql.
...user_last_timestamp in table user_newtalk already modified by patch patch-use
r_newtalk-user_last_timestamp-binary.sql.
...pt_title in table protected_titles already modified by patch patch-protected_
titles-pt_title-varbinary.sql.
...ir_type in table ipblocks_restrictions already modified by patch patch-ipbloc
ks_restrictions-ir_type.sql.
...index wl_namespace_title already set on watchlist table.
...job_title in table job already modified by patch patch-job-job_title-varbinar
y.sql.
...job_timestamp in table job already modified by patch patch-job_job_timestamp.
sql.
...job_token_timestamp in table job already modified by patch patch-job_job_toke
n_timestamp.sql.
...wl_notificationtimestamp in table watchlist already modified by patch patch-w
atchlist-wl_notificationtimestamp.sql.
...role_id in table slot_roles already modified by patch patch-slot_roles-role_i
d.sql.
...model_id in table content_models already modified by patch patch-content_mode
ls-model_id.sql.
...cl_to in table categorylinks already modified by patch patch-categorylinks-cl
_to-varbinary.sql.
...log_title in table logging already modified by patch patch-logging-log_title-
varbinary.sql.
...us_timestamp in table uploadstash already modified by patch patch-uploadstash
-us_timestamp.sql.
...index up_property already set on user_properties table.
...index site_global_key already set on sites table.
...index log_type_time already set on logging table.
...fa_name in table filearchive already modified by patch patch-filearchive-fa_n
ame.sql.
...oi_name in table oldimage already modified by patch patch-oldimage-oi_name-va
rbinary.sql.
...exptime in table objectcache already modified by patch patch-objectcache-expt
ime-notnull.sql.
...index ar_name_title_timestamp already set on archive table.
...img_name in table image already modified by patch patch-image-img_name-varbin
ary.sql.
...img_timestamp in table image already modified by patch patch-image-img_timest
amp.sql.
...index si_key already set on site_identifiers table.
...rc_title in table recentchanges already modified by patch patch-recentchanges
-rc_title-varbinary.sql.
...rc_timestamp in table recentchanges already modified by patch patch-recentcha
nges-rc_timestamp.sql.
...rc_id in table recentchanges already modified by patch patch-recentchanges-rc
_id.sql.
...index rc_new_name_timestamp already set on recentchanges table.
...ar_title in table archive already modified by patch patch-archive-ar_title-va
rbinary.sql.
...page_title in table page already modified by patch patch-page-page_title-varb
inary.sql.
...user_name in table user already modified by patch patch-user_table-updates.sq
l.
...index rev_page_timestamp already set on revision table.
...have modtoken field in objectcache table.
...index oi_timestamp already set on oldimage table.
...index page_name_title already set on page table.
...index ct_rc_tag_id already set on change_tag table.
...page_restrictions table does not contain pr_user field.
...fa_id in table filearchive already modified by patch patch-filearchive-fa_id.
sql.
...img_major_mime in table image already modified by patch patch-image-img_major
_mime-default.sql.
...linktarget table already exists.
...rev_page_id key doesn't exist.
...pr_page in table page_restrictions already modified by patch patch-page_restr
ictions-pr_page.sql.
...pp_page in table page_props already modified by patch patch-page_props-pp_pag
e.sql.
...ir_value in table ipblocks_restrictions already modified by patch patch-ipblo
cks_restrictions-ir_value.sql.
...have tl_target_id field in templatelinks table.
...user_autocreate_serial table already exists.
...ir_ipb_id in table ipblocks_restrictions already modified by patch patch-ipbl
ocks_restrictions-ir_ipb_id.sql.
...ipb_id in table ipblocks already modified by patch patch-ipblocks-ipb_id.sql.
...user_editcount in table user already modified by patch patch-user-user_editco
unt.sql.
Running maintenance/migrateRevisionActorTemp.php...
revision_actor_temp does not exist, so nothing to do.
done.
...revision_actor_temp doesn't exist.
Running maintenance/updateRestrictions.php...
Migration is not needed.
done.
...page table does not contain page_restrictions field.
...templatelinks table has already been migrated.
...tl_namespace field does not exist in templatelinks table, skipping modify fie
ld patch.
...templatelinks table does not contain tl_title field.
...have el_to_path field in externallinks table.
...have user_is_temp field in user table.
Running maintenance/migrateRevisionCommentTemp.php...
revision_comment_temp does not exist, so nothing to do.
done.
...revision_comment_temp doesn't exist.
Running maintenance/migrateExternallinks.php...
Old fields don't exist. There is no need to run this script
done.
...el_to field does not exist in externallinks table, skipping modify field patc
h.
...have pl_target_id field in pagelinks table.
...externallinks table does not contain el_to field.
Running maintenance/fixInconsistentRedirects.php...
Fixing inconsistent redirects ...
Estimated redirect page count: 1
0/0
Done, updated 0 of 0 rows.
done.
...img_size in table image already modified by patch patch-image-img_size_to_big
int.sql.
...fa_size in table filearchive already modified by patch patch-filearchive-fa_s
ize_to_bigint.sql.
...oi_size in table oldimage already modified by patch patch-oldimage-oi_size_to
_bigint.sql.
...us_size in table uploadstash already modified by patch patch-uploadstash-us_s
ize_to_bigint.sql.
...wb_changes table already exists.
...wb_id_counters table already exists.
...wb_items_per_site table already exists.
...ips_site_page in table wb_items_per_site already modified by patch /var/www/h
tml/extensions/Wikibase/repo/includes/Store/Sql/../../../sql/mysql/archives/Make
IpsSitePageLarger.sql.
...wb_ips_site_page key doesn't exist.
...change_info in table wb_changes already modified by patch /var/www/html/exten
sions/Wikibase/repo/includes/Store/Sql/../../../sql/mysql/archives/MakeChangeInf
oLarger.sql.
...wbt_text table already exists.
...wb_terms doesn't exist.
...wb_changes_change_type key doesn't exist.
...index change_object_id already set on wb_changes table.
...change_time in table wb_changes already modified by patch /var/www/html/exten
sions/Wikibase/repo/includes/Store/Sql/../../../sql/mysql/archives/patch-wb_chan
ges-change_timestamp.sql.
...wb_id_counters_type key doesn't exist.
...wb_changes_dispatch doesn't exist.
...wbc_entity_usage table does not contain eu_touched field.
...babel table already exists.
...babel_lang in table babel already modified by patch /var/www/html/extensions/
Babel/sql/babel-babel_lang-length-type.sql.
...babel_level in table babel already modified by patch /var/www/html/extensions
/Babel/sql/babel-babel_level-type.sql.
...entityschema_id_counter table already exists.
...oauth_registered_consumer table already exists.
...have oarc_oauth_version field in oauth_registered_consumer table.
...have oarc_oauth2_is_confidential field in oauth_registered_consumer table.
...have oarc_oauth2_allowed_grants field in oauth_registered_consumer table.
...have oaac_oauth_version field in oauth_accepted_consumer table.
...oauth2_access_tokens table already exists.
...index oaat_acceptance_id already set on oauth2_access_tokens table.
...oaac_accepted in table oauth_accepted_consumer already modified by patch /var
/www/html/extensions/OAuth/schema/mysql/patch-oauth_accepted_consumer-timestamp.
sql.
...oarc_email_authenticated in table oauth_registered_consumer already modified
by patch /var/www/html/extensions/OAuth/schema/mysql/patch-oauth_registered_cons
umer-timestamp.sql.
...site_stats is populated...done.
Populating rev_len column
...doing rev_id from 1 to 200
Populating ar_len column
...archive table seems to be empty.
rev_len and ar_len population complete [0 revision rows, 0 archive rows].
Populating rev_sha1 column
...doing rev_id from 1 to 200
Populating ar_sha1 column
...archive table seems to be empty.
rev_sha1 and ar_sha1 population complete [0 revision rows, 0 archive rows].
Populating and recalculating img_sha1 field

Done 0 files in 0.0 seconds
Populating fa_sha1 field from fa_storage_key

Done 0 files in 0.0 seconds
Updating *_from_namespace fields in links tables.
...doing page_id from 1 to 200
Adding empty categories with description pages...
Removing empty categories without description pages...
Category cleanup complete.
Populating page_props.pp_sortkey...
Populating page_props.pp_sortkey complete.
Updated a total of 0 rows
Copying IP revisions to ip_changes, from rev_id 0 to rev_id 1
Attempted to insert 0 IP revisions, 0 actually done.
Purging caches...done.

Done in 0.1 s.

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

Done!
You might want to run rebuildrecentchanges.php to regenerate RecentChanges,
and initSiteStats.php to update page and revision counts

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
STEP 7

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

** Rebuilding fulltext search index (if you abort this will break searching; run
 this script again to fix):
Dropping index...
Clearing searchindex table...Done
Rebuilding index fields for 61 pages...

Rebuild the index...
Done.


** Rebuilding recentchanges table:
Rebuilding $wgRCMaxAge=31536000 seconds (365 days)
Clearing recentchanges table for time range...
Loading from page and revision tables...
Inserting from page and revision tables...
Updating links and size differences...
Loading from user and logging tables...
Flagging bot account edits...
Flagging auto-patrolled edits...
Removing duplicate revision and logging entries...
Deleting feed timestamps.
Done.


** Rebuilding links tables -- this can take a long time. It should be safe to ab
ort via ctrl+C if you get bored.
Refreshing links from pages...
Estimated page count: 61
Deleting illegal entries from the links tables...
  Checking interval (-INF, INF)
    pagelinks: 0 deleted.
    imagelinks: 0 deleted.
    categorylinks: 0 deleted.
    templatelinks: 0 deleted.
    externallinks: 0 deleted.
    iwlinks: 0 deleted.
    langlinks: 0 deleted.
    redirect: 0 deleted.
    page_props: 0 deleted.
Done.

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
STEP 8

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

2024-06-24 13:44:05 recentChangesUpdate Special:RecentChanges type=purge namespa
ce=-1 title=RecentChanges requestId=8bd4b280623528ed036c2901 (id=1,timestamp=202
40624134321) STARTING
2024-06-24 13:44:05 recentChangesUpdate Special:RecentChanges type=purge namespa
ce=-1 title=RecentChanges requestId=8bd4b280623528ed036c2901 (id=1,timestamp=202
40624134321) t=3 good
...
2024-06-24 13:44:14 htmlCacheUpdate Item:Q13 table=templatelinks recursive=1 roo
tJobIsSelf=1 rootJobSignature=d3355aa146adc6d13bd99a42a0ece7c75a15ff7c rootJobTi
mestamp=20240624134400 causeAction=create-page namespace=120 title=Q13 requestId
=de9b1d642539543afbbade49 causeAgent=unknown (id=129,timestamp=20240624134400) S
TARTING
2024-06-24 13:44:14 htmlCacheUpdate Item:Q13 table=templatelinks recursive=1 roo
tJobIsSelf=1 rootJobSignature=d3355aa146adc6d13bd99a42a0ece7c75a15ff7c rootJobTi
mestamp=20240624134400 causeAction=create-page namespace=120 title=Q13 requestId
=de9b1d642539543afbbade49 causeAgent=unknown (id=129,timestamp=20240624134400) t
=0 good

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
STEP 8.5

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

Rebuilding $wgRCMaxAge=31536000 seconds (365 days)
Clearing recentchanges table for time range...
Loading from page and revision tables...
Inserting from page and revision tables...
Updating links and size differences...
Loading from user and logging tables...
Flagging bot account edits...
Flagging auto-patrolled edits...
Removing duplicate revision and logging entries...
Deleting feed timestamps.
Done.

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
STEP 9

*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

Refresh Site Statistics

Counting total edits...243
Counting number of articles...1
Counting total pages...61
Counting number of users...2
Counting number of images...0

Updating site statistics...done.

Done.

What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
 
*******************************************************************************
NOTE: Do not run maintenance scripts directly, use maintenance/run.php instead!
      Running scripts directly has been deprecated in MediaWiki 1.40.
      It may not work for some (or any) scripts in the future.
*******************************************************************************

Query OK, 0 row(s) affected
Query OK, 1 row(s) affected
Query OK, 1 row(s) affected
stdClass Object
(
    [id_type] => 16
    [id_value] => 0
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id_type] => 20
    [id_value] => 0
)


What's next?
  Try Docker Debug for seamless, persistent debugging tools in any container or
image → docker debug wbdocker-wikibase-1
  Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/debug-cli/
(base)

EDIT 1: Per @DavidMaze's recommendation, I split the above script into external and internal scripts; the external script is as follows and is run first:
#!/bin/sh

# Load config.ini
source config.ini

cd "$WBDOCKERPATH"

# Run docker-compose to set up Wikibase Suite instance.
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.extra.yml up -d

# Copy over XML dump to upload.
docker cp "$XMLDUMPPATH" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/tmp/dump.xml

# Copy over rebuild script.
if [ ! -f "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql" ]; then
    curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JeroenDeDauw/c86a5ab7e2771301eb506b246f1af7a6/raw/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql -o "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql"
fi
docker cp "$WBWRAPPERPATH/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/www/html/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql

# Copy over internal Docker script.
docker cp "$WBWRAPPERPATH/wbdocker_internal_wrapper.sh" wbdocker-wikibase-1:/var/www/html/wbdocker_internal_wrapper.sh

Then I run the wbdocker_internal_wrapper.sh inside the container wbdocker-wikibase-1:
#!/bin/sh

# Run update and install vim and Python.
apt -y update
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-get -y install vim

# Run update script.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/update.php --force

# Update LocalSettings.php to allow for entity import.
if grep -Fxq "\$wgWBRepoSettings['allowEntityImport'] = true;" /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php;
then
    :
else
    echo "\$wgWBRepoSettings['allowEntityImport'] = true;" >> /var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
fi

# Import dump.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/importDump.php < /var/tmp/dump.xml

# Rebuild.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/rebuildall.php

# Run jobs.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/runJobs.php --memory-limit 512M

# Initialize site stats.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/initSiteStats.php --update

# Run rebuild script.
php /var/www/html/maintenance/sql.php /var/www/html/rebuildWikibaseIdCounters.sql

Unfortunately this also fails and the error Could not create a new page. It already exists. persists.

I'd avoid doing as much work as you're doing via docker exec – anything you do there will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Do you need a custom Dockerfile to install the dependencies and extension?  An entrypoint wrapper script to do the setup and import?

@DavidMaze totally understand-- would an alternative be to copy in the bash script and run it from within the container? (To be clear I don't currently have a custom Dockerfile, I'm running it exactly as it is out-of-the-box)

I'd recommend including the script via a Dockerfile COPY directive.  You can RUN some of the steps like including the extensions only once, instead of repeating them every time the container restarts.  You can build an image FROM any image you'd like, including extending the prebuilt image you're currently running.

@DavidMaze edited to add what I modified the scripts to be; it definitely is much cleaner and more readable. It unfortunately leads to the same error, but at least now I know it isn't Docker-shenanigans.
